# How can I use the word sorry

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb-forms

What is correct
He was sorry to come late last night.
Or
He was sorry about coming late last night.

Answer (score 0):

Both **sorry + *to-infinitive*** and **sorry about + *gerund*** are acceptable and natural.

The flaw in your examples are that *to come* and *coming* are lacking an object - where is it that he arrived late? If you use that particular verb without an object, it may be taken with a particular intransitive meaning - even if it's obviously not what you intended, it may lead to snickering, depending on your audience. Even without that (wilful) misunderstanding, it comes across as ambiguous and incomplete.